# Oracle Update Command: Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

| UniqueID | Parcel_id | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38077 | 025 07 0 031.00 | 410 ROSEHILL CT, GOODLETTSVILLE |
| 43076 | 025 07 0 031.00 | (NULL) |

```
UPDATE h 
SET address = COALESCE(h.address, h2.address)
FROM   housing h
       JOIN housing h2
         ON h.parcel_id = h2.parcel_id
WHERE  h.unique_id <> h2.unique_id
       AND h.address IS NULL;
```

What I need to do is to populate the Address field for null records using address from same parcel id but for different unique ids.

-- Select Query is currently displaying the records by populating the null fields

```
SELECT h.unique_id,h.parcel_id,h2.parcel_id,h.address,h2.address, coalesce(h.address,h2.address) 
FROM housing h, housing h2 
WHERE h.parcel_id = h2.parcel_id
AND h.unique_id <> h2.unique_id AND h.address is null;
```

I'm trying to update values which have same parcel id but address column is null, please suggest if there any other way around it or where im wrong here.

I hope im clear this time. Sorry for any mistakes this is my first time posting here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support that non-standard UPDATE FROM syntax.

Comment: It doesn't support that syntax [until 23c](https://medium.com/@andrei.manoliu/update-and-delete-statements-via-direct-joins-in-oracle-database-23c-f68990cfa997) anyway. Also you've shown three statements - presumably the error is from the update run on its own? Not sure why the other two are there, particularly the `create`?

Answer (score 0):

Use update or merge in the following form(s):

```
update h set
  h.address = (select coalesce(h.address, h2.address)
               from housing h2
               where h2.parcel_id = h.parcel_id
                 and h2.unique_id <> h.unique_id
              )
where h.address is null;


merge into h
  using housing h2
  on (h2.parcel_id = h.parcel_id
      and h2.unique_id <> h.unique_id
     )
  when matched then update set
    h.address = coalesce(h.address, h2.address)
  where h.address is null;
```

Though, it is kind of *strange* you specified both `coalesce` and `where` clause because:

- `where` says that only rows whose `h.address is null` are to be updated, while
- `coalesce(h.address, h2.address)` says that you should put `h2.address` into `h.address` **if** `h.address` is null

Therefore, remove one of these; `coalesce` is probably a better choice (to be removed) as `where` causes less rows to be affected, so performance might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I tried using your method but it isn't working as well, merge query is retuning : " unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables" and the update command is not working as well

Comment: It means that there are *duplicates* so Oracle doesn't know which row to use. You'll probably have to modify join conditions (to further restrict rows returned), apply DISTINCT, maybe one of aggregates (such as MIN or MAX) ... it depends on data you have.

Comment: @arpittguptta: "update command is not working" - Please don't ever just say something is not working. Are you getting an error message? Which? I agree with Littlefoot, that it seems the subquery returns more than one row for an address. It will only work if there are no more than two rows per parcel_id, for if there are more, which other row shall the DBMS take the address from? It seems you must define a better rule how to choose the h2 row.